# Imposing the condition very very less than in a function

Tags: function-comparison

I have two functions, say f[x,y] and g[x,y]. I want to impose the condition that when x<<y, f[x,y]=a and g[x,y]=0, and when x>>y, f[x,y]=0, and g[x,y]=b. How do I write the above piece of information in code?

Comment: What did you try? Does `Piecewise` fail?

Comment: "Much much less" is too vague for code. You will have to decide on a threshold for your comparison and then look into e.g. `Piecewise` or `If` or `Boole`.

Comment: Much much less than as in the sense that there is a certain finite difference value between x and y. Even imposing that condition would work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a range for difference.

```
result[x_, y_] = x + y
f[x_, y_, e_] := Piecewise[{{a, x > y && Abs[x - y] > e}, 
                            {b, y > x && Abs[x - y] > e}}, result[x, y]]
```

Here `e` determines whether the difference in values is too large.

```
f[1, 9, 2]
```

> b

```
f[9, 1, 2]
```

> a

```
f[9, 8, 2]
```

> 17